# Trying to undestand why using \zs in regex is not working as I expect

Tags: regular-expression, search

Consider the following test String:

```
County,Age,Age_group,Gender,Jurisdiction,Travel_related,Origin,EDvisit,Hospitalized,Died,Case_,Contact,Case1,EventDate,ChartDate,ObjectId
```

If use the following regex to search:

```
\v((.{-},){9})\zsDied
```

I get the expected result of having the word Died in the test String be matched.

If I use the following regex instead to search:

```
\v((.{-},){9})\zsEvent
```

I also get a match.  This is confusing to me, as the String Event is not immediately following the String matched by the zero width pattern: `\v((.{-},){9})\zs`

If I then use the following:

`\vDied,\zsEvent`

`\vDied,\zsCase`

The first one does not match and the second one does match, both as I would expect. If somebody here could explain this inconsistency in behavior, I would greatly appreciate it.

I ran these tests on gvim 8.2 on Linux.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing the `\zs` and looking the highlighting makes it pretty clear what is happening; `/\v((.{-},){9})Event`.  This regex spells "(match anything non-greedily, followed by a comma) 9 times, followed by Event."

There are two problems here:

1. Although it is not greedy, `.{-}` may also match comma, whenever necessary to form a full match.
2. Even if 1 were not true, you don't specify an anchor like `^`, so the match may occur anywhere.  There are certainly 9 Word-comma strings before Event.

Comment: Thank you very much.  After reading over your observations here is the pattern that I came up with to basically do what I want: */\v^([^,]{-},){9}\zs*.  This basically is going to skip past the first 9 comma delimited columns

Answer (score 2):

> String Event is not immediately following the String matched by the zero width pattern: `/\v((.{-},){9})\zs`.

It actually is. That pattern will match *at least* 9 commas separating fields, but it will actually match them later in the line as well. So while you won't be able to match `Hospitalized`, `EDvisit`, `Origin` or the other fields that precede `Died`. On the other hand, it will match `Case_`, `Contact`, `Case1`, `EventDate` and the other fields that come after `Died`.

There are two issues preventing the regex to match *only* the tenth field (the one preceded by exactly 9 commas.) The first issue is that `.` will match any character, *including* a comma. You can fix that by using `[^,]` instead of `.`. Second, you don't have an anchor to the start of the string. You can easily add one with `^`.

Result: `/\v^(([^,]{-},){9})\zsDied`. This will work with the field `Died`, but not with any other field. You can actually simplify this regex, since you don't need a pair of parents. You don't need the `{-}` non-greedy repeat anymore, since `[^,]` will not match the commas. Simplified regex: `/\v^([^,]*,){9}\zsDied`.

Hopefully this also makes it clear why `/\vDied,\zsEvent` won't match (`Event` doesn't follow `Died,`), while `/\vDied,\zsCase` does. It doesn't really have anything to do with the `\zs` itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer as well, and for further simplifying what I was ultimately trying to do